# CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to check the duplicate values in my SQL table. and remove those data.

So I first checked the duplicate values using

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
      [Se_Id],
      [Service_Previous_Step],
      [Service_Next_Step]
FROM   [Mondo-PROD].[dbo].[ServiceWorkflows]
GROUP BY
        [Se_Id],
        [Service_Previous_Step],
        [Service_Next_Step]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Then I use this

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ServiceWorkflows] 
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_ServiceWorkflows_ServiceId_PreviousStep_NextStep 
UNIQUE ([Service_Id], [Service_Previous_Step], [Service_Next_Step]);
```

But I get errors as

> The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.ServiceWorkflows' and the index name 'UQ_ServiceWorkflows_ServiceId_PreviousStep_NextStep'. The duplicate key value is (96, 1, 2).

Comment: Adding a constraint does not delete duplicated data. If data should be deleted, you need to execute a delete command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DELETE to remove duplicates from your table like:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT [Se_Id],
      [Service_Previous_Step],
      [Service_Next_Step],
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Se_Id ORDER BY Se_Id)
   FROM [dbo].[ServiceWorkflows] 
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

If your table already has duplicate records in it then adding a constraint won't delete the duplicate records and hence the error which you are getting.